# How to get the selected value from ajax.net ComboBox through javascript

Tags: javascript, combobox, ajax.net

I need to get the selected value from an ajax.net combobox throught javascript so that I can do some client side validation.

What's the best way to do this?
Thanks,

---

I've been able to get the value with this:

```
var combo = $get('ddlComarcas');
var comboHidden = $get('ddlComarcas_HiddenField');
var o4 = combo.getElementsByTagName('li')[comboHidden.value].childNodes[0];

alert('"' + o4.data + '"');
```

But I still need to trim the value from o4.data. Anyone can point how to do that visual studio 2008 jquery?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery or just use DOM:

jQuery:

```
var selection = $('#selectID').val();
```

DOM:

```
var selection = document.getElementById("selectID").value;
```

asp.net -> server side

javascript -> client side

Comment: Thanks but your solution doesn't work. The combobox from the ajaxtoolkit is made up of 3 inputs. I can't get the value with that.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is value doesnt exist client side so it cant be retrieved. There are easier ways to get index tho (assuming whatever initialization is complete).

```
selected index:         $find("<%=cboName.ClientID%>").get_hiddenFieldControl().value;
selected index (again): $find("<%=cboName.ClientID%>").get_selectedIndex();
selected text:          $find("<%=cboName.ClientID%>").get_textBoxControl().value;
```

As far as I can tell, validating a combobox on the client requires some faith in index or text, or some kind of server side workaround.

To provide a direct answer to the subject line, a javascript array could be created server side with each combobox value and then referenced client side by selected index...

codebehind:

```
 // write combobox values to asp:literal
 foreach (ListItem i in cboName.Items)
         litCboValues.Text += "\"" + i.Value.Replace("\"", "\\\"") + "\", ";
 litCboValues.Text = litCboValues.Text.TrimEnd(new char[] {',', ' '});
```

aspx:

```
<script>
// array of values
 var cboValues = [ <asp:Literal id="litCboValues" runat="server" /> ];

// add an alert to the combobox to test
function pageLoad()
{
  $find("<%=cboName.ClientID%>").get_textBoxControl().onblur = function () { 
    alert( cboValues[$find("<%=cboName.ClientID%>").get_selectedIndex()] );
  };
}
</script>


<asp:ComboBox id="cboName" runat="server" ...
```

Answer (score 0):

this works (today) in IE and Chrome - about the only thing ie is good for is the debugger f12 (- you can browse through the watched objects

Following
            
              
            

            // i do it on button but you could probably do it on a combo event 
      Follow

```
 function addFollowed() {
      var combo = $get('<%= FollowListBox.ClientID %>'); 
      var toFollow = combo.control._textBoxControl.value;
```